# Setup that uses additional files

Tags: c#, installation, wix, windows-installer, ini

I have the requirement to deliver a software that can be adjusted by the customer. I would therefore like to have a setup for my software that uses additional files.
For example the customer should be able to decide which images are getting used in the software before installing it. Also I would like to place an ini file next to the setup in which the user can define some strings that will be used in the software itself after the setup.

Is it possible to create a setup file (.msi) that copies files that are in the same folder as the setup itself to the program folder?

Additionally I would like to include some of the images and strings from the ini file that the user places in the same folder as the setup for the setup itself. I am using WIXUI and want to adjust the default images and text in the setup dialog.

I have added a custom action:

```
<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="CopyToSystem32" ExeCommand="copy myfile.xml c:\test"
                  Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" 
                  Return="asyncNoWait" />
</Fragment>.
```

Unfortunately it is not getting executed. If I change the command to "md test" it works but I can not get the copy command to work. Any ideas? Cheers!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What changes should the user do? Are there lots of changes, or just images and some text?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul Changing some strings in a text file would be enough

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to create a setup file (.msi) that copies files that are in the same folder as the setup itself to the program folder?

I'm not familiar with MSI packaging, but in theory your MSI package may run a script or a separate executable after installation, which in it's turn will do everything you want.

Comment: Yes, you can copy files in custom action (script) manually to the install location. Problem is, that those files are not registered as part of MSI in windows, so if you uninstall/repair installer, those files will not be removed/repaired.

Comment: I have added a custom action:<Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id="CopyToSystem32" ExeCommand="copy myfile.xml c:\test" Directory="TARGETDIR" Impersonate="no" Execute="deferred" Return="asyncNoWait" />
  </Fragment>. Unfortunately it is not getting executed. If I change the command to "md test" it works but I can not get the copy command to work. Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: @Mischo5500 You may ask it as a separate question here